# google contact profile picture

Tags: .net, oauth, gdata-api, google-data-api

I am getting contacts using following API call:

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?max-results=1000&
```

The user is authenticated with following scopes:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
```

I get response upon calling contacts as following:

```
<entry>
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/testemail%40gmail.com/base/15</id>
    <updated>2011-07-21T10:41:27.893Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
    <title type="text">Wilson Mark</title>
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo" type="image/*" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/testemail%40gmail.com/15/MgeOWd0mxw4xdDrA0vWQRQ" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/testemail%40gmail.com/15" />
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/testemail%40gmail.com/full/15" />
    <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/testemail%40gmail.com/full/15/1311244887893000" />
    <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" address="wilson.mark@gmail.com" primary="true" />
  </entry>
```

**Queries**:

Q1. I do not get gd:etag in photo tag for any user though so many users in my contacts does have profile picture. Am I missing any scope or making some wrong call.

Q2. How can I get profile photo? If I make following authorized call

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/15/MgeOWd0mxw4xdDrA0vWQRQ
```

I get 404 not found error. If I remove the code at end, and keep url till 15/, I get 401 unauthorized error.

thanks

Comment: have you tried this scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile i am able to get user profile and any asocited profile user have with his/her account?

Comment: Hi, I tried as per your suggestion but getting same result as in my post. I've been getting records for all contact with similar entry tag for all records. I read on google developer guidelines, that image tag will contain gd:etag when a user has a profile pic else not. I am getting everything except that etag when I'm sure that contacts do have profile pic. thanks anyways. Your scope was new to me.